# var_dump returns false when it should return true

Tags: php

I have a problem. I have made a form where a logged in user can signup to be a photographer. This works all great. On that page I check if the user isn't already a photographer by seeing if the photographer object is empty.

Like this:

```
if(!empty($this->user->oPhotographer)){         
            $this->doRedirect('alreadyapplied');
}
```

Now when I do a `var_dump` on `!empty($this->user->oPhotographer)`
it returns `bool(false)`. It shouldn't return this, it should return true because I'm testing with a user that has a filled photographer object.

Now the strange thing :

```
echo '<pre>'.var_dump(!empty($this->user->oPhotographer)).'</pre>';
        if(!empty($this->user->oPhotographer)){         
            $this->doRedirect('alreadyapplied');
        }
        
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump(!empty($this->user->oPhotographer));
        print_r($this->user->oPhotographer);
        echo '</pre>';
```

This piece of code should redirect to the proper page when the object is not empty. The var_dump still gives false, though it doesn't redirect. This is the code output:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
photographer Object
(
    [table] => photographer
    [data] => 
    [className] => 
    [arFields] => Array
        (
            [id] => id
            [country] => country
            [dateofbirth] => dateofbirth
            [street] => street
            [city] => city
            [about] => about
            [dateapplied] => dateapplied
            [user_id] => user_id
            [phone] => phone
            [zip] => zip
        )

    [id] => 1
    [country] => ...
    [dateofbirth] => ...
    [street] => ...
    [city] => ...
    [about] => 
    [dateapplied] => 2013-04-28 19:41:08
    [user_id] => 15
    [phone] => ...
    [zip] => ...
)
```

How can it return false when the photographer is actually not empty?

Comment: use isset() not empty

Comment: Empty explicit check isset

Comment: That's strange and maybe unfair. But i'll do it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have used "isset", not "empty". The reasons are pretty clear.
For more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php